# Return string (or char *) from a C function

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need a function to return a string of various sizes.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_option_argument(char *arg, char *shortopt, char *longopt) {
    int len = strlen(arg) ;
    size_t len_shortopt = strlen(shortopt) ;
    size_t len_longopt = strlen(longopt) ;

    // we add an extra space to provide the case when shortopt is included in longopt
    char shortopt2[len_shortopt + 1] ;
    char longopt2[len_longopt + 1] ;

    strcpy(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
    shortopt2[len_shortopt] = ' ' ;
    strcpy(longopt2, longopt) ;
    longopt2[len_longopt] = ' ' ;

    // previous version who doesn't work
    /* strcat(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
    strcat(shortopt2, " ") ;
    strcat(longopt2, longopt) ;
    strcat(longopt2, " ") ; */

    // printf("%s, %s\n", shortopt2, longopt2) ;

    int shortopt_boucle = 0 ;
    int longopt_boucle = 0 ;
    int find_shortopt = 0 ;
    int find_longopt = 0 ;
    int j = 0 ;
    int k = 0 ;

    // We browse arg until we reach the end or find an option.
    for (int i=0; i<len && !(find_shortopt || find_longopt); i++) {
        // if we are not already browsing and we have found a potential start for one
        if (!shortopt_boucle && arg[i] == shortopt2[0]) {
            shortopt_boucle = 1 ;
            j = 0 ;
        }
        // same for longopt
        if (!longopt_boucle && arg[i] == longopt2[0]) {
            longopt_boucle = 1 ;
            k = 0 ;
        }
        // if we are procuring a potential option, we check the current character
        if (shortopt_boucle && j <= len_shortopt)
            if (arg[i] == shortopt2[j])
                j++ ;
            else
                j=0 ;
        // idem
        if (longopt_boucle && k <= len_longopt)
            if (arg[i] == longopt2[k])
                k++ ;
            else
                k=0 ;
        // if we have found one, then stop the loop and use i or j variable to mark the start of the option
        if (j == len_shortopt + 1)
            find_shortopt = 1, j = i+1 ;
        if (k == len_longopt + 1)
            find_longopt = 1, k = i+1 ;
    }

    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char)*len) ; // on utilise une allocation dynamique pour pouvoir le retourner

    // get the word just after the option marker
    if (find_shortopt)
        for (int i=0; arg[j+i] != ' ' && arg[j+i] != '\0' && j+i < len ; i++)
            result[i] = arg[j+i] ;
    else if (find_longopt)
        for (int i=0; arg[k+i] != ' ' && arg[k+i] != '\0' && k+i < len ; i++)
            result[i] = arg[k+i] ;

    return result ;
}

void affiche_vache(char *arg) {
    char *eyes = get_option_argument(arg, "-e", "--eyes") ;
    char *hat = get_option_argument(arg, "-h", "--hat") ;
    if (strlen(eyes)!=2)
        eyes = "oo" ;
    if (strlen(hat)!=6)
        hat = " ^__^ " ;
    char *corp1 = "____" ; // this part is for a next implementation
    char *corp2 = "    " ;
    char *corp3 = "----" ;
    printf("         \\ %s\n", hat) ;
    printf("          \\ (%s)\\_%s__\n", eyes, corp1) ;
    printf("            (__)\\ %s  )\\/\\\n", corp2) ;
    printf("                ||%sw |\n", corp3) ;
    printf("                ||     ||\n") ;
    free(eyes) ;
    free(hat) ;
}

int main() {
    affiche_vache("-e 00 -h _|@#|_") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

the function `get_option_argument` must extract an option from a given string.
For example, `get_option_argument("-e $$", "-e", "--eyes")` must return `"$$"` and does when I call it for the first time, but then it goes wrong.

I think the problem is about memory.
I first use this way to declare my string: `char result[size]` but it cause a segmentation fault and the following warning: `function returns address of local variable`.
That's why I use `malloc`, but seems like it doesn't really work.
Does `malloc`  allocate memory in a different place each time?
And the lines with `free` are commented out because it's provoked segmentation fault.

I apologize for my noisy example, I try to reproduce the same situation with simpler code, but I don't really understand when it's working or not.

Comment: you're right in that you cannot return a local char array, since it dies on function return. Using `malloc` is the correct procedure for memory allocation to persist outside of the function. You lose me from there, why are you immediately `free`ing `eyes` after `get_option_argument`? As soon as you try to use `eyes` after that you invoke undefined behavior. You must use it and then `free` it when you no longer need it. It also looks like you're failing to NUL terminate the string you return.

Comment: First thing I've spotted: 'free(eyes) ; . . . if (strlen(eyes)!=2)` . Once you free the buffer pointed to by eyes, it is not valid to try to access the contents of the buffer you no longer have. Also, malloc _may or may not_ allocate memory in a different place each time depending on stuff. Your code must not depend on either behavior.

Comment: Also, you can't switch between having char *'s pointing to malloc'ed buffers and string literals so cavalierly. malloc'ed buffers must be freed, string literals cannot be and you must not try to do so.

Comment: the free just after define eyes was for a try (I forget to remove it).

Comment: @jeanfaure Your edit invalidates this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78103938/2410359).  Best to rollback your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behaviours from the first lines.

`shortopt2` and `longopt2` are uninitialized and `strcat` requires a valid C sting as the destination. Also they are too short to accommodate the space `" "`

```
    char shortopt2[len_shortopt + 2] ;
    char longopt2[len_longopt + 2] ;

    strcpy(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
    strcat(shortopt2, " ") ;
    strcpy(longopt2, longopt) ;
    strcat(longopt2, " ") ;
```

Also `strlen` returns `size_t` not `int`.

I didi not analyze the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code to allocate space for your options:

```
char shortopt2[len_shortopt + 1] ;
char longopt2[len_longopt + 1] ;

strcat(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
strcat(shortopt2, " ") ;
strcat(longopt2, longopt) ;
strcat(longopt2, " ") ;
```

But the scond call to `strcat` is overwriting the null terminator in the arrays, which will allow further code to walk off into the sunset. You need to replace the above four lines with:

```
strcpy(shortopt2, shortopt);
strcpy(longopt2, longopt);
```

I can't figure out exactly what those loops in the following code are doing but I suspect you could again go past the end of either string as you are using the length of the array is the terminal value in the `for` loops, rather than `length - 1`. You may need to run this through the debugger to see exactly where it is failing and which variables are the cause.

Also note Yano's comment about the early `free` of your `malloc`'ed arrays.

Comment: Even the *first* `strcat()` is incorrect, since the target is required to be a valid C string.

Comment: The target will be a valid string, as strcat adds a terminating null. If it did not then further calls to that function would fail.

Comment: There is no terminating nul to start with, so no valid c string. Local variables have no initialisation. The answer is partly right, saying that the first must be  `strcpy()` but I don't get your "will overwrite the string terminator". of course it does, it is supposed to, and will add another.

Comment: ...I think I see what you mean: the arrays are **too small**, being only large enough for the first string, and not the 'space string' which is concatenated.

Comment: Yes, but the second null terminator will be beyond the end of the array. If he wants a space character after the main string, then the length needs to be `len_shortopt + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out!
In fact, the bug comes from the strcat,
Thanks to @OldBoy I add this: `printf ("%s, %s\n", shortopt2, longopt2);` in my code just after the concerned line to check, and it had shown this:
After calling

```
char *eyes = get_option_argument(arg, "-e", "--eyes") ;
char *hat = get_option_argument(arg, "-h", "--hat") ;
```

the code prints successively,

```
-e , --eyes 
-e -h , --eyes --hat
```

Meaning that for an obscure reason (there is certainly a good reason for that but for me it's incomprehensible), the variable `shortopt2` and `longopt2` keeps it content. So that's why the function doesn't find anything during the second call.
So I modify

```
strcat(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
strcat(shortopt2, " ") ;
strcat(longopt2, longopt) ;
strcat(longopt2, " ") ;
```

to

```
strcpy(shortopt2, shortopt) ;
shortopt2[len_shortopt] = ' ' ;
strcpy(longopt2, longopt) ;
longopt2[len_longopt] = ' ' ;
```

And now it's work perfectly !

But if someone has an idea of why these variables keep their content...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).